# Hovering a navbar item to change into the next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to switch from section 1 to section 2 of the page, when using the mouse to hover the buttons in the navigation bar **without clicking them**.

How should I do so?

and here is the code in below:

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
     top:0;
    left:0;padding: 5px;
}

.container a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
#topNav {
    margin-bottom:0;box-shadow: none;background:none;
}


body {
  position: relative;
}
#section1 {padding-top:120px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
#section2 {padding-top:120px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
#section3 {padding-top:120px;height:500px;color: #000000; background-color: #FFD2E9;}
#section4 {padding-top:120px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="topNav">
  <div class="container">
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <a href="#section1">Toehold Switch</a>
            <a href="#section2">Interlab</a>
            <a href="#section3">Charaterization</a>
            <a href="#section4">Program</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: what do mean by "change to section 2" here? you mean the selection/highlight?

Comment: for example, The page scroll down from Toehold switch to interlab

Comment: your html code looks wrong, please check it and correct!

Comment: I have checked it, nothing is missing......where is the mistake?

Comment: @AlanChiu still not clear. You want some mouse hover effect or on scroll section change effect?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo I just want to know can I use the mouse to stimulate a scroll section change effect, by touch the buttons in Navbar but not click into them?? The code being showed above has been traditional scroll section effect already......

Comment: @AlanChiu correct me if am wrong. You wanted to scroll to particular section on hover of respective nav. Am i right?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Yes, you are right. Do you have any idea to finish this?

Comment: @AlanChiu check below fiddler on answer, and let me know if you need clarifications.

Comment: I have an Idea.. have a look here in this site and hover the **gallery** button on the navbar and see if it's desired for you, or not! if yes, i will answer you : [**click here for the link**](http://theweb.gigfa.com)

Comment: @alireza kay yes, your idea is good

Comment: @AlanChiu have you tried my fiddler?

Comment: Oh , I tried it :D It works but it scroll down too fast....How can I change it slower? @Rajesh RiJo    Moreover, Thank you for helping me :D

Comment: @AlanChiu It's simple. Just change the animate function duration. $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(sectionTo).offset().top
    }, 2000); Please mark it as answer, if it helps.

Comment: I've answered what to do for reaching the solution which I said before in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with CSS alone. You are suppose to use scripts. Take a look on the [fiddler][1] for your reference.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/c9xonwdL/1/
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use jQuery

- **FIRST:** define an **id** for the 'navbar item' which you want to hover.

for example add `id: "item1"` for the "Toehold switch" element in your navbar:

```
<a href="#section1" id="item1">Toehold Switch</a>
```

- **SECOND:** **append** the **jQuery library** to your project:

one way, is to add its link to the html `header` :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

- **THIRD:** add this javascript **script** code to your html:

  ```
  <script>

  $("#item1").hover(function () {
     var hash = $("#item1").attr("href");

      var scroll = $(hash.toString()).offset().top;

      event.preventDefault();
      $('body,html').animate(
          {scrollTop: (scroll)},
          1000,
          function () {
              window.location.hash = hash;
          }
      );
  });

  </script>
  ```

**TIP 1**: by using the script, if you hover the "toehold" link on the navbar, it will scroll to the section which you were linked to (i.e. 'section 1')

**TIP 2**: you can also change the speed of scrolling in the `animate()` function in the script tag: just change '1000' to whatever you want. (that is 1000 ms i.e. 1 second)!